# videokit.so load fail in marshmallow and above API ffmpeg android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am working with ffmpeg commands for various operation on videos & images & its working fine on devices having API 22 & below version but when i set targetSdkVersion 23 or 24 at that time my app is going to crash and i am getting :

```
error like videokit.so load fail:/data/user/0/packagename/lib/libvideokit.so.
```

Comment: I am getting the same error and could not find any solution yet, have you resolved this ?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani no still could not found any solution. is seems ffmpeg library error for API level 23 and above.

Comment: had you used ffmpeg and target Api to 22 ? or looked for another library instead of ffmpeg ?

Comment: I have used ffmpeg with target Api 22. do you have idea about any other library ?

Comment: MediaCodec is another library but there is no better documentation available on internet and it require minimum Api level 18 .. Ref : http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Answer (score 0):

The FFMPEG source code contains something called text-reloacations.

Starting Marshmallow, the Android OS does not allow linking to native code libraries that contain text-relocations. This means that Marshmallow can't be targeted (i.e. targetSdk=23 or up) if you link to videokit.so.

The FFMPEG ticket on this issue is concluded with someone suggestion that they [won't fix the problem](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4928).

Google, on their side, [won't fix it either](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191235).

Stalemate.